# How to fix ios app crashing with certain name?

Tags: xcode, ios, xcode4

I have an app called "FirstAid" that crashes in the simulator and on a device. If I create a clean project called "FirstAid" that also crashes with the same report. Any other named app is fine.

I have done a clean, and rebuilt it but it still crashes.

How do I fix it?

```
2011-05-14 10:06:39.912 FirstAid[1217:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00ef55a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01049313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00ef54e1 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x008c7677 _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 135
    4   Foundation                          0x008c75e5 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 285
    5   UIKit                               0x0034330c -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 112
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00e6b8cf -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 239
    7   UIKit                               0x00341d23 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1041
    8   UIKit                               0x00343ab7 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 168
    9   UIKit                               0x0014917a -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFile] + 172
    10  UIKit                               0x00149cf4 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 291
    11  UIKit                               0x00154617 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533
    12  UIKit                               0x0014cabf -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
    13  UIKit                               0x00151f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x013ce992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00ed6944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00e36cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00e33f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00e33840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00e33761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    20  UIKit                               0x001497d2 -[UIApplication _run] + 623
    21  UIKit                               0x00155c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    22  FirstAid                            0x00001cb9 main + 121
    23  FirstAid                            0x00001c35 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Answer (score 0):

This error may mean several things, but my bet is that some of your outlets (from IB) is broken. Examine your XIB-files + all their outlets and make sure they exist in your code as well.

Comment: In particular, check the custom class of your main window. If you changed the app name, that class' name might have changed as well. So your XIB file might still reference to old class.

Comment: I copied all the files to a different location and created a new project with a different name and it worked. I deleted the project. Created a new one with the same name (ViewBased) clicked on run and it failed with the above error. So I'm thinking it has something to do with XCode leaving some files somewhere.